# Using a node class

Tags: c++

```
node *temp; 
temp->dataItem = newPassenger;
if(size == 0)
{
    Head = temp;
    Tail = temp;
}
else
{
    Tail->nextNode = temp;
    Tail = temp;
}
size++;
```

I need help as VS keeps saying that `temp` is not initialized, I have little experience with C++. My node class is as follows

```
#include "passenger.h"
#pragma once
class node
{
public:
    node();
    passenger dataItem;
    node * nextNode;
};
```

Comment: What kind of help are you looking for? `temp` is in fact not initialized.

Comment: You declared a pointer.  You did not make it point to anything before you used it.  You did not allocate any nodes for it.

Answer (score 1):

```
node *temp = new node; 
temp->dataItem = newPassenger;
if(size == 0)
{
    Head = temp;
    Tail = temp;
}
else
{
    Tail->nextNode = temp;
    Tail = temp;
}
size++;
```

Answer (score 1):

You should read more introductory C++ books. This usually gets covered pretty early.

You should write

```
node *temp = new node;
```

This will reserve the space for a node in memory. When you're done with this node, you should write

```
delete temp;
```

You must make sure you don't delete something twice, because this will cause your program to crash.

Answer (score 0):

```
node *temp; 
temp->dataItem = newPassenger;
```

If the above is really your code, then the compiler's quite right - you're deferencing `temp` without having initialised it.  You probably want something like this:

```
node* temp = new node;
temp->dataItem etc...
```